# Restricting logged in user to access the front page of login and registration without log out

Tags: python, django

Like in facebook. after logging in users are prompted to user homepage. but it prevents the logged in users to going back to login page unless users logout. so how to prevent the logged in users from going back after loggin in

```
 def register(request):
    form = self.register_form(request.POST)
    if request.method=='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            firstName=form.cleaned_data.get('firstName')
            lastName=form.cleaned_data.get('lastName')
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account successfully created!')

            return redirect('login')


    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})


    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html',redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),

# path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='logout'),
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home:index'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried?

Comment: when logged in, users will be redirected to userdashboard 'home:index'. and i want to prevent logged in users from accessing the login and register page whic is in another app of this url
    path('',views.frontpage,name='frontpage'),

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `redirect` the user to the home page even if the user clicks the `login/signup` link.

For this you can do something in the `login` and `signup` views:

```
def login(request):
    # if the user is already logged in, redirect to user home page
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # redirect to the home page
    else:
        # do something like defining get or post method request conditions 

def signup(request):
    # if the user is already logged in, redirect to user home page
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # redirect to the home page
    else:
        # do something like defining get or post method request conditions
```

This is one way to redirect the `logged in user` to the home page even if the user clicks the login/signup link or tries going back to the login page.

Comment: redirecting to homepage is of no problem. i want to prevent logged in users to access the initial page where we do signup and register

Comment: Well as per your query, you want the user not to be able to go to the login page. So I assume that the user can only go to the login page though some url like `/login`. The `view` being called by this `url` can be made to redirect to the user home page if the user is logged in. So, in this way, the user can't be able to reach the login page unless the user is logged out.

Comment: Also have you tried using this answer in practice? If not then can you show what you have tried so that I can get a better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Below are some option. try reading django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/

***Option 1***

This can be one of the way. You check if the user is logged in and return suitable html page.

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
  if not request.user.is_anonymous:
     return render("home.html")
  else:
     return render("login.html")
```

***Option 2***

Check if the user is logged in , if so redirect to home page endpoint

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.contrib.auth import login_required
    def login(request):
       if not request.user.is_anonymous:
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')

    @login_required
    def home(request):
       # Render you home page response
```